# How to insert XML tags into a microsoft word 2022 document, export this document as xml, and get only the tags+infos in between in a new xml file

Tags: xml, ms-word, tags, version, export-to-xml

I'd like to **insert XML tags into a word document** to grab some information, same as this guy.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0DoQkecvnI
My mindset is to keep something simple when i take notes from my courses.

This works only with M-S word < 2010. Structure xml pane is not available anymore.I did this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-xmlnodes-controls-to-word-documents?view=vs-2022 but  Structure xml pane is still not opening.
I am on M-S word 22. Should i use a specific macro ? or import an add in ? The last add in from ms word for xml is only for 2019 version.

And after i'd like to export my XML document to put it into anki (free open software)  and make flash cards to study and improve my efficiency....
I would like only to have the different tags with my notes in between.

Does anyone know how I could do this ? I don't find any solution for my microsoft word version.

Thanks to anyone who will help me,

Gilles

Comment: The basic difficulty with Custom XML is that Microsoft removed the feature after a lawsuit in the USA. Now, Word removes any Custom XML it finds when it opens a document. So it's not just the missing structure pane  that's the problem - you will lose all your custom tags as soon as you save, close, re-open your notes. Difficult to suggest an alternative that does anything like the same thing without a lot more effort. NB, "Custom XML" and "Custom XML Parts" are not the same thing, which can cause confusion too.

Comment: Aouch so sad. And if i try to do same kind of things with json file ? would it be more realistic ? What do you mean by a lot more effort ? Do you know if there are specific macro that can directly export my tags into and xml document even if i lose them from the original doc after closing it ?  Thanks

Comment: Microsoft tried to eliminate Active X Controls back in 2005.  You probably still have one of these controls inside your word document.

Comment: A "lot more effort" because there is no other built-in facility that lets you choose from a set of predefined names and let's you "tag" a part of the text. Personally, I'd probably write some VBA that presented me with the list of tags I wanted to use, then marked the current selection or perhaps a point in the document with  a uniquely named bookmark based on the tag name. Then (somehow) extract what I needed into the format I needed when I saved my document. Neither theWord object model nor VBA have any built-in support for JSON, but nothing prevents you from using it.